# Displaying JavaScript variable inside div fails

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to display my JavaScript variable inside div col. I just can't get it displayed. Even with inspector it doesn't have a value.
However, if I display it outside of every div, so in the beginning of the page it works..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firma = "test d.o.o.";
  document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = firma;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p><span style="z-index: 9999 !important;" id="insert"></span></p>
</div>
```

Here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/th5wydn1/10/

Thank you for your help. Greetings

Comment: I don't know how did you manage that but you have (in your fiddle) this: <script id="insert">TEST</script>. You can look at it in web inspector on the fiddle page. That's your problem.

Comment: I don't know if I am missing something haha, but sorry, I can't. It has to be in the top of the page between the image and HTTPS://dummypage.com. and It is not here. : https://imgur.com/a/ulWn1WZ

Comment: Change the `id` from `insert` to `foobar`both in the HTML and in the JS.

Comment: What a weird bug

Comment: The "insert" name you used is already used, put any other `id` name, and it will work.

Comment: Changing insert to foobar doesn't do anything to my page in localhost

Comment: @devZ did you change both the id from the JavaScript `document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = firma;` and the HTML element to `id="foo"`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/20vbu8ad/ All I've done is change `insert` to `foobar` **both in the HTML and the Javascript**.

Comment: How does the `<script id="insert"></script>` even get there and how does it even run when we later add innerHTML to it? Seems like a hack or malware

Comment: Yes, take a look https://imgur.com/a/tFCoi44

Comment: Connexo forked YOUR fiddle. It works there

Comment: Yes I see. but it doesn't work in my local page and I copy-pasted code haha..

Comment: Did you check both the console and the network tab for errors in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: @devZ Check if all the code is added to the fiddle just in case you missed anything that causes an issue in your localhost. To make sure this is an error check the inspector -> console and see if anything is there. Otherwise, try restarting your localhost server.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help. After restarting apache web server it works now.. What a pain

Answer (score 3):

If all you did is copy and paste the code, your local page doesn't have jQuery.

Either add that, or replace your one line of jQuery code with native Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var firma = "test d.o.o.";
  document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = firma;
});
```

Comment: @devZ make sure to check this out, could be your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jquery Syntax. Means you need include the JQuery Lib. For example add this CDN script link above your closing body tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firma = "test d.o.o.";
  document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = firma;
});
```

```css
<div>
  <p><span style="z-index: 9999 !important;" id="insert"></span></p>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p><span style="z-index: 9999 !important;" id="insert"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello change "*insert*" word , maybe this keyword,or busy**

```
<span style="z-index: 9999 !important;" id="_insert"></span>


$().ready(function() {
            const firma = "TEST";
            document.getElementById("_insert").innerHTML = firma;
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vc75dmnx/